# Zookeeper accepting and closing unexpected socket connection even before Kafka is run

Tags: sockets, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper is accepting a socket connection from 50167(in my case) and then closed it.

```
[2017-09-04 14:44:23,926] INFO Server environment:user.dir=C:\kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:44:24,013] INFO tickTime set to 3000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:44:24,029] INFO minSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:44:24,045] INFO maxSessionTimeout set to -1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:44:24,245] INFO binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-09-04 14:45:16,525] INFO Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50167 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory)
[2017-09-04 14:45:16,557] INFO Client attempting to establish new session at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50167 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:45:16,572] INFO Creating new log file: log.b1 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog)
[2017-09-04 14:45:16,613] INFO Established session 0x15e4c2b5f7f0000 with negotiated timeout 6000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50167 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2017-09-04 14:45:17,939] INFO Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15e4c2b5f7f0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
[2017-09-04 14:45:17,970] INFO Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:50167 which had sessionid 0x15e4c2b5f7f0000 (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
```

Due to this, Kafka server is also failing to run. Any solution will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After, I deleted the old logs at location:
[image: Kafka folder structure]

i.e. folders kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0kafka-logs & kafka_2.11-0.11.0.0zookeeper-data, the server started fine.